# How to identify that two separate unit tests are part of the same build in TFS?

Tags: c#, tfs

I've got two separate unit tests in my TFS project. When I run all tests, I want the test functions to understand that they are part of a single test run. I'm not quite sure how the run would be identified. Maybe by a guid?

It might look something like this:

```
=== test1.cs ===
[TestClass]
public class Test1
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void verifyFoo()
    {
        int i = get_current_run_guid();
        ...

=== test2.cs ===
[TestClass]
public class Test2
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void verifyBar()
    {
        int i = get_current_run_guid();
        ...
```

Is this possible in TFS?

Comment: Seems against the whole idea of unit tests... but maybe I'm not fully understanding this.

Comment: are you trying to group tests together in lists or do you need to share data among them? sharing data is really bad and all your tests will become brittle and you'll end up ignoring them because you can't trust them.

Comment: are your tests in different projects or same project/dll?

Comment: Yes, believe it or not I am trying to share some information between them. I realize that's generally speaking not a great design idiom, but so far it's the best I've got.

Comment: @CosminOnea They're in the same project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always have that giud in a shared static field.

```
public class SharedData
{
    public static Guid TestRunId = Guid.NewGuid();
}
```

Your tests can simply use it:

```
=== test1.cs ===
[TestClass]
public class Test1
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void verifyFoo()
    {
        Guid i = SharedData.TestRunId;
        ...

=== test2.cs ===
[TestClass]
public class Test2
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void verifyBar()
    {
        Guid i = SharedData.TestRunId;
        ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can build test lists. These lists allow you to select te test you would like to execute in a testrun. You will then have to configure your build process to select the testlist it needs to execute for a build.

see ref here: http://geekswithblogs.net/jakob/archive/2009/06/03/tfs-team-build-2010-running-unit-tests.aspx